# is there a method in pandas which can detect if a value is in the range of available columns in the df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which looks like this. [the structure of the df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSAB2.png)

df.to_dict() prints this.

```
{'Score': {0: '100-199', 1: '200-300', 2: '400-500', 3: '500-700'}, '50-60%': {0: 0.2, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.5}, '60-70%': {0: 5.6, 1: 6.4, 2: 7.2, 3: 8.4}, '70-80%': {0: 6.8, 1: 7.9, 2: 8.6, 3: 9.5}}
```

I want to write a function which can detect what value to pick from this df. For example if I put 124,70 I want to get the value 6.8 from it. How can I do that? The pseudocode would look like this.

```
def get_value(124,70):
    # go through the columns consisting of range and selecting the value that the 
    # arguments pertain to.
    # return that value
```

Comment: please provide the DataFrame as DataFrame constructor, not image! (`df.to_dict()`)

Comment: Use [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) for both your index/columns, then you can simply do `df.loc[124,70]`.

Comment: The function is pretty much straightforward from your comment. What have you tried?

Comment: the column names got range in it. it is not that straight forward. that is why I am asking this question. Otherwise I would have used '' in df but the value that I am giving in the function is not present in the column and row of dataframe. @QuangHoang

Comment: Please follow stackoverflow guidelines in submitting questions   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: provided the df.to_dict(). kindly check please. @mozway

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it
Create additional columns for the range and then search

```
var = 220 # value to search
df[['from','to']] = df['Score'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)
df[(var >= df['from'])  & (var <= df['to'] )]
df
```

Comment: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I missed during copy/paste, updated the code

Comment: added astype(int) in the split, second line

Comment: it is now just printing the df. added extra two columns to and from. but it is not printing/getting the value for 220. and it would need to parse also the columns of percentage range. then need to see what is the real value. from the df I provided for example, if I put 220 and 63% in the function I should get 6.4

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @QuangHoang, you can use IntervalIndexes

To convert from your format:

```
score = df['Score'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(score[0], score[1])

percent = (df.drop(columns='Score').columns.to_series()
             .str.split('[-%]', expand=True)[[0,1]].astype(int)
           )
col = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(percent[0], percent[1])

df2 = df.set_axis(idx).set_axis(col, axis=1)
```

output:

```
            (50, 60]  (60, 70]  (70, 80]
(100, 199]       0.2       5.6       6.8
(200, 300]       0.3       6.4       7.9
(400, 500]       0.4       7.2       8.6
(500, 700]       0.5       8.4       9.5
```

Then use:

```
df2.loc[124, 70]
```

output: `5.6`

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '620 – 639'

Comment: then use `str.split(' – ', ...)` you have a different separator (not a `-` like shown in your example). If you have a mix, you could use: `str.split(r'\D+', ...)`

Comment: now it is giving ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements

Comment: You need to provide your real data, the provided example is clearly not representative